# Qual a diferença entre os comandos 'git pull' e 'git fetch'?

Tags: git, versionamento

Eu gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre os comandos `git pull` e `git fetch` no software de versionamento git.

Comment: Tem um [livro muito bom](http://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/), disponível em Português para consulta online. Vale MUITO a pena ler...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`git fetch` baixa as referências ([*refs*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References)) com nomes ou tags de um ou mais repositórios (caso você tenha outro remote além do `origin` configurado), junto com os objetos necessários para completá-los. Basicamente ele atualiza as referências locais com relações às remotas, mas não faz o merge com o branch local.

`git pull` incorpora mudanças de um repositório remoto para o branch local. É equivalente a `git fetch` seguido de `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Referências:

- [`git pull`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)
- [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

Answer (score 23):

De modo simplório, o `git fetch` buscas as diferenças em relação ao ramo atual, mas não altera nada nesse branch. Já `git pull` faz o `git fetch` e faz o merge das diferenças.

Comment: Isso mesmo, corrigido.

Answer (score 14):

`git fetch` faz download dos ultimos commits do branch remoto, mas nao os incorpora com a copia actual do repositorio. Estes commits so estarao disponiveis no branch `origin\master`, e o branch `master` continua intacto.

`pull` equivale a fazer `git fetch` (download dos ultimos commits) + `git merge` (incorpora os commits com o branch local)

Ver [`git pull` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> git pull is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.
>
> git pull e' um atalho para `git fetch` seguido de `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

Este comportamento por defeito pode ser alterado para executar `fetch` + `rebase` , em vez de `fetch` + `merge`, com a flag `git pull --rebase`