# Qual a diferença entre "git push" e "git sync"?

Tags: git

Depois que eu faço um `git commit` para guardar as alterações no meu repositório local, consigo enviá-las para o repositório remoto usando tanto o comando `git push` quanto usando o comando `git sync`. Qual a diferença entre estes dois comandos do Git?

Comment: Como o renanzin falou, um resumo bom que eu acho é que o git sync vai deixar seu repositório local e nuvem iguais Eu iniciei com o git a pouco tempo e se for o como o meu caso eu uso o GitHUB eles tem um cliente muito rápido para usar https://desktop.github.com

Comment: qual versão do git tem sync, no meu diz que não existe esse comando!?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`git push`: Realiza o upload do conteúdo do repositório local para o remoto

`git sync`: Primeiro executa um `git pull` que baixa o conteúdo do repositório remoto e atualiza o local, após isso, é executado o `git push` que faz o que foi mencionado acima.

[Resposta sobre o git pull](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3237/77268)