# Como fazer git pull em todas as branches?

Tags: git

Tenho varias branches e fazendo duas versões de um scripts, em branches separadas em um servidor de desenvolvimentismo. Então como atualizar todas as branches, do clone, no servidor de produção?

Comment: git pull --all não resolve?

Comment: @epx fiquei em duvida entre ```git fetch --all --prune``` e ```git pull --all```, estava esperando uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: É, por isso coloquei como comentário, não tenho certeza se atende seu caso de uso em particular.

Comment: @MárcioMocellin Se espera que a resposta apresente essa diferença, faça essa pergunta. Você pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar algo como "vi que existem esses dois comandos ... qual a diferença?". Porém, isso já foi respondido em [Qual a diferença entre os comandos 'git pull' e 'git fetch'?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3231/5878)

Comment: Já achei a resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você deva mesclar-las em uma branch só e depois enviar esta única para o repositório. Posso estar falando besteira então faça um teste antes em uma cópia.
Exemplo : https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging